# How to calculate number of map and reduce need to set?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Want to set number of map and reduce in the slave servers.
Ideally how many maps should be configured on slave servers?

Comment: It depends. And you can't really set the exact number of maps AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

No of mappers are set by default .
No of mappers are equal to no of input splits. You can only set no of reducer task.